Age distribution of a population described by a renewal process
I have a problem of interest in modeling a certain type of data. My limited research so far in solving this problem leads me to believe that it requires knowledge of Renewal Theory to solve, which I am missing. Would anyone be able to provide a solution and walk me through how to arrive at it?
In particular, I would like to use observations of 2.) to arrive at an estimate of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
Problem
Imagine a town of large population where the lifespan of its inhabitants upon birth is described by a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$. In this town the population is fixed, so that each time someone dies, another person is born.

Given enough time, what will be the steady state distribution of age in this town?
Given an observation period of $T$ years, where $T << \mu$, what is the probability you will observe a randomly-selected citizen die?


Normal distribution doesn't look right. It admits a non-zero probability that a lifespan is negative.

@user58697 Good point I hadn't noticed. In this case, I am using normal to approximate the limit of a gamma distribution with large $k$. How would you resolve this?
